# ¿Cómo puedo convertir el contenido de un div en una imagen jpg o png usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

La idea es convertir el div y su contenido en una imagen **jpg** o **png** y el tamaño de la misma sea el **width** y el **height** que ya están definidos.

¿Cómo puedo crear esto usando javascript? alguna librería de javascript que pueda usar.

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.content-img{
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.content-img > p{
padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-img">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In orci libero, molestie vitae mi quis, congue mollis justo. Vivamus accumsan, ex nec efficitur efficitur, diam enim varius dui, hendrerit lobortis nisi risus nec elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: has visto html2canvas?

Comment: Hola! Alguna vez use esta libreria http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ , tal vez te puede servir.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza Canvas

Te relaciono las librerías necesarias para que te empapes

```
https://superal.github.io/canvas2image/canvas2image.js
https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
```

El siguiente ejemplo se relacionado al código que enviaste. la única diferencia es que se agrego y evento Click, Que lo asocias a un `input:Type['button']` eso es todo. Descarga la imagen del `DIV`.

Código Jquery segu ejemplo relacionado

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#crear-imagen").click(function() {
          html2canvas($('#content-img')[0]).then(function(canvas) {
          return Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
          $(".response").append(canvas);
   });
  });
```

Saludos espero te sirva